# PHP stops after a few minutes

Tags: php, nginx, debian

I have an webserver under Debian 8.11 with MySQL 5.5, NGINX 1.15.12 and PHP 5.6 running since 3 years.
A few weeks ago, PHP stops work after a few minutes. After I reload PHP, everything works for a few minutes again.
I just update PHP to version 7.2 but the problems still exists. There are around 30 vHosts on this server.
I have no idea, how to find out, what the problem is.

Could someone give me some tips, where or what to check?

Comment: What do you mean PHP stops? all pages stop working?

Comment: Yes, none of the pages working. After "service php7.2-fpm restart" everything works just for a few minutes.

Comment: What do you mean with "after I reload PHP"? Did you check the logs? system (for crashes and permissions) and ngix. They are in `/var/log/`. It is possibly you have some old program in PHP which are exploited (on logs it is normal to find special crafted strings to cause buffer overflow). -- BTW this is a question for unix.stackexchange.com or ServerFault.com (sister sites), not on topic for this site.

Comment: @bee did you got any solution for that?